# Will a magnetic field damage a laptop charging brick?

Tags: electricity, magnetic-fields

I recently got a Dell laptop for school. It has a charger, like the one below. [image: Charger]

Being the good student that I am, I applied my knowledge about electricity flowing in a loop and began wondering if I was producing a magnetic field by using my charger like that.

So my question is: Will leaving the brick resting in a constant magnetic field somehow damage it?

The power output is 130 watts and there are ten coils. Would the magnetic field even be consequential?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This coil is known as [bifilar coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifilar_coil) that would not produce a magnetic field even if you connect the laptop, because the current in the positive and negative wires has the opposite direction and its magnetic field is canceled out. Having said this, switching power supplies are very durable and would not be affected by such a moderate magnetic field even of a real coil.

Comment: They could overheat, though!